# Check if user role and in category?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to create function for Wordpress which will...

**Scenario 1**
is this post in Art Artist category...oh yes it is...than continue if...
is this user checking the post from Art Artist category an Contributor...oh yes he/she is...continue...
show him or her art_artist shortcode content

**Scenario 2**
is this post in Art Artist category...oh yes it is...than continue if...
is this user checking the post from Art Artist category an Contributor...oh no he/she is not...show him or her this...
**No bro!**

**Scenario 3**
is this post in Art Artist category...oh no it is not...than continue whatever...

Something like this...

```
<?php
$user = wp_get_current_user();

if ((in_category('Art Artist')) && in_array('contributor', (array)$user->roles))
{
    echo do_shortcode('[art_artist]');
}
elseif ('is category art artist but is not contributor')
{
    echo 'No bro!';
}
else
{
    echo do_shortcode('[art_artist]');
};
?>
```

Comment: hey, just following up to see if my answer helped? :)

Answer (score 0):

You were pretty much already there.

Your logic needed is within the first if condtional, all you need is `!` prefixed before the `in_array`.

`!` - means (in this context): if condition is **NOT** met. So you're if/elseif should look like:

```
if ((in_category('Art Artist')) && in_array('contributor', (array)$user->roles)) {
    echo do_shortcode('[art_artist]');
} elseif ((in_category('Art Artist')) && !in_array('contributor', (array)$user->roles)) {
    echo 'No bro!';
}
```